# Update Trigger to work even if field isn't populated

Tags: trigger, soql, case

I wrote this Trigger that works fine.

```
trigger UpdateCaseOwner on Case (before insert, before update) {
    for(Case c : Trigger.New) {
        if(c.Sub_Type__c == 'Run Lines' || c.Sub_Type__c == 'Nitro Gen' || c.Sub_Type__c == 'Swaps' ){
            User user = [Select Id From User Where Name = :c.Bev_Carb_Manager__c];
            c.OwnerId = user.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the field `Bev_Card_Manager__c` on the case is empty then the Trigger gives an error. How can I account for that so that if no value exists, the Trigger won't throw me an error and still allow the case to save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Set<String> userNames = new Set<String>();
Set<String> subtypes = new Set<String>{'Run Lines', 'Nitro Gen', 'Swaps'};

for(Case c : Trigger.New) {
    if(subtypes.contains(c.Sub_Type__c)){
        userNames.add(c.Bev_Carb_Manager__c);
    }
}

userNames.remove(null);

if(!userNames.isEmpty()){
    Map<String, User> userNameToIdMap = new Map<String, User>();
    for(User u : [SELECT Id, Name FROM User WHERE Name IN :userNames AND IsActive = true]){
        userNameToIdMap.put(u.Name, u);
    }

    for(Case c: trigger.new){
        if(subtypes.contains(c.Sub_Type__c) && userNameToIdMap.containsKey(c.Bev_Carb_Manager__c)){
            c.OwnerId = userNameToIdMap.get(c.Bev_Carb_Manager__c).Id;
        }
    }
}
```

There's a similar question where I explained why I'm doing it this way: [Is this good coding practice?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34030/is-this-good-coding-practice)